# Calling a python function running in Azure VM from an Android Client

Tags: python, android, azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I have a python program running in Azure VM, I need to trigger a particular function from that program as soon as a button is clicked in an android APK (android Client), this there a way to do that, if yes please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what are you looking for is [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/functions/). You can create an HTTP triggered function in azure, on python, call it and get the work done. It will be on the consumption plan, pay for use with free of costs for some (Number of Executions, Estimated Execution Time (ms), Memory Size).

Check out the official docs here: [Azure Functions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions)

Comment: thank you, That was helpfull